The difference between two Jacobian formulations in Extended Kalman Filter
Given a state vector $\mathbf{x}$ and a non-linear measurement prediction function $\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$, the Jacobian is defined as:
$$
\mathbf{J} \triangleq \frac{\partial \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}.
$$
However, some authors define the Jacobian  as:
$$
\mathbf{J} = \frac{\mathbf{e}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\partial (\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{h}(x))}{\partial \mathbf{x}},
$$
where $\mathbf{z}$ is the measurement. Essentially, the second formulation is taking the partial derivatives of the residual with respect to the state vector. This seems to introduce a sign difference, but I can't seem to find an explanation on why one is better than the other.

Look close at the math and see if the resulting Jacobians are treated differently depending on how they're generated (i.e., added in one place, subtracted in the other).

It does introduce a sign difference, but that's the only difference since $\mathbf{z}$ is constant. One isn't any "better" than the other.
